# Setting values through result of DataFrame.loc saved in variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to set values through the result of `DataFrame.loc`, but after saving it in a variable?

For example, given a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]})
```

I can select a subset of `y` based on the values of `x` and change their values in one line:

```
df.loc[df['x'] > 1, 'y'] = 7
```

However if I save the result of that `loc` call in a variable, assignment into the variable simply change the variable, not the `Series` it points to:

```
sel = df.loc[df['x'] > 1, 'y']
sel = 9
```

Is there a method on `Series` that performs the same operation as with `df.loc[...] = ...`?

Comment: You're question isn't entirely clear to me. But I believe you want `pd.Series.loc`

Comment: @alexwhitworth I think what OP wants to do is create a reference to those locations, and then be able to update them at the same time using `sel = 9`

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because you're updating the value of the variable `sel`, not the value of `df.loc[df['x'] > 1, 'y']`. It's like if you did `df = 0`, it wouldn't change every value in the df to be 0, it would just make the `df` variable be the integer 0

Comment: You want to save a view, this *could* be possible, under specific circumstances, with **slices of several items** but not with a single item. Why don't you save the  indexer/slicer?

Comment: Even if I take a slice of all columns `sel = df.loc[df['x'] > 1, :]`, I still cannot assign through to the original DataFrame with it: `sel.loc[:, 'y'] = 9`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this the **sel.loc** modifies the values in the view (this will also modify the original dataframe, so you can use a copy first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 5, 6]})        
sel = df.loc[df['x'] > 1, 'y']        
sel_copy = sel.copy()
sel_copy.loc[:] = 9        
print(sel_copy)



# Update the original DataFrame based on sel_copy
df.loc[df['x'] > 1, 'y'] = sel_copy
print(df)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That doesn't work. While it does modify the cells in the view, it does not modify the cells in the original DataFrame.

Comment: Hey sean, if I understood well this is the result you are expecting.